# How To Search and Replace Text in ActiveX TextBox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to search an ActiveX TextBox (TextBox1) to replace a phrase with nothing...

I have this code that seems to just wipe the entire box rather than the phrase in isolation.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()


TextBox1 = Selection


Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "This is the text to remove!"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


End Sub
```

With some additions (like selecting all shapes in the active document)- the code works with an ordinary TextBox - and with the rest of the document too... just not the ActiveX box (which is what I want!!)

Please help!

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't change the text in `TextBox1` at all. It would find and replace text in the document body.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the built-in VBA [**Replace function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264409.aspx):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    TextBox1.Value = Replace(TextBox1.Value, "This is the text to remove!", "")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much - stress over!